# Studies On The Affect Of Immunotherapy On Larynx Surgeries

Tags: cancer, immune-system, clinical-study, reference-request, throat

I've been searching online for a study regarding the affect of immunotherapy on the necessity for an affected individual diagnosed with laryngeal cancer to require larynx surgery, to no avail.

Could somebody point me in the right direction of where I could find such a study (assuming one exists)?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: @Thomas Specifically, I'm searching for a study regarding whether subjects diagnosed with HNSCC are less likely in need to undergo surgery following the administration of some form of immunotherapy

Comment: Please describe what HNSCC is.

Comment: Did you try simply googling HNSCC + immunotherapy? [The first hit](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6685871/) is an overview with references to relevant studies.

Comment: @Thomas Head and neck squamous cell carcinoma

Comment: @CareyGregory unfortunately, none of which reference this subject in particular